# Image Loading Filckers in List View - Android

Tags: android

I have getView as follow

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater tempinflator = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = tempinflator.inflate(R.layout.event_list_item, null);
    }


    img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.businessLogo);


    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tour_default);


    int loader = R.drawable.tour_default;
    String image_url = event.getBusinessLogo();

    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);

    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, img);
    return convertView;
}
```

image_url = internet address of image

and ImageLoader method as follow

```
 public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
{
    stub_id = loader;
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(loader);
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out why image is getting flickered. Is there any way to load image from URI in a list view? without flickering?

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "flickers"? Is this when the image comes back from the server or when you're loading something from the cache?

Comment: First time it loads from server then it should be saved in cache. but image disappears and come back.